# How to get two separate results from a Foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops

I have shortened a monthCalender date down to the day selected value.

```
 string dMC = dateMonthCalender.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
                 string takeDMCDay = dMC.Substring(0, 2);

                 monthCalender = Convert.ToInt32(takeDMCDay)
```

I have a List which stores fields that are read from a text file in a List of class communityevents objects( day,time, name, description etc...)

One of the fields is called e.Day ( which is the day in the month)

When the user picks a day on the month calender it fills a combobox with the e.Name of events due that day.

The problem I'm having is in the CreateEventList method.
If the value is true it does what i want. 
but if I uncomment the not equal to method it overrides the first

How do i fix this please, i can guess that the problem is the foreach communityEvent is the issue , but I am lost in how to get a one or the other not both to run, I've tried else if, if else, tried while loops and so on but here I am.?

```
private void CreateEventList()
      {
         events = ExtractData();
         eventComboBox.Items.Clear();

         string eventTrue = ("-Events-");
         string descriptTrue = ("Pick an event");
         string eventFalse = ("-No Event-");
         string descriptFalse = ("-No events today-");
         foreach (communityEvent e in events)
         {
            if (monthCalender == e.Day)
            {
               eventComboBox.Items.Insert(0, eventTrue);
               eventComboBox.Items.Add(e.GetName());
            }
          //else if (monthCalender != e.Day)
            //{
            //   eventComboBox.Items.RemoveAt(0);
            //   eventComboBox.Items.Insert(0, eventFalse);
            //}
         }
      }
```

Comment: wouldnt that be simpler if `ExtractData` took a parameter indicating which Date you wanted data for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `-No Event-` on the list if there are no events on the selected month. Otherwise you want a list of matches.

That would be something close to

```
  private void CreateEventList()
  {
     events = ExtractData();
     eventComboBox.Items.Clear();

     string eventTrue = ("-Events-");
     string descriptTrue = ("Pick an event");
     string eventFalse = ("-No Event-");
     string descriptFalse = ("-No events today-");

     if ( !events.Any( e => e.Day == monthCalender ) )
     {
       // no occurrences
       eventComboBox.Items.Insert(0, eventFalse);
     } 
     else
     {
       // there are some occurrences
       eventComboBox.Items.Add(eventTrue);
       foreach (communityEvent e in events)
       {
        if (monthCalender == e.Day)
        {
           eventComboBox.Items.Add(e.GetName());
        }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thats it perfect, thanks very much Wiktor Zychia and also Plutonix.